# CIFAR10 dataloader sampler split

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, pytorch

i am trying to split the training data of CIFAR10 so the last 5000 of the training set is used for validation. my code

```
size = len(CIFAR10_training)
dataset_indices = list(range(size))
val_index = int(np.floor(0.9 * size))
train_idx, val_idx = dataset_indices[:val_index], dataset_indices[val_index:]
train_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(train_idx)
val_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(val_idx)

train_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(CIFAR10_training,
                                          batch_size=config['batch_size'],
                                          shuffle=False,  sampler = train_sampler)
valid_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(CIFAR10_training,
                                           batch_size=config['batch_size'],
                                           shuffle=False,  sampler = val_sampler)
print(len(train_dataloader.dataset),len(valid_dataloader.dataset),
```

but the last print statement prints 50000 and 10000. should it not be 45000 and 5000
when i print the train_idx and val_idx it prints the right values([0:44999],[45000:49999]
is there anything wrong with my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot replicate your results, when I execute your code, the print statements outputs twice the same number : the number of elements in `train_CIFAR10`. So I guess you made a mistake when copying your code, and `valid_dataloader` is actually given `CIFAR10_test` (or something like that) as parameter. In the following, I'm gonna assume that it's the case, and that your print outputs `(50000, 50000)`, which is the size of the training part of Pytorch's CIFAR10 dataset.

Then it is completely expected, and no it should not output (45000, 5000). You are asking for the length of `train_dataloader.dataset` and `valid_dataloader.dataset`, i.e the **length of the underlying datasets**. For both your loaders, this dataset is `CIFAR10_training`. Therefore you will get twice the size of this dataset (i.e 50000).

You cannot ask for `len(train_dataloader)` either, because you that would yield the number of batches in your dataset (approximately `45000/batch_size`).

If you need to know the size of your splits, then you have to compute the length of your samplers:

```
print(len(train_dataloader.sampler), len(valid_dataloader.sampler))
```

Besides this, your code is fine, you are correctly splitting your data.

Comment: okay i see what you mean and what i am doing wrong, thank you @trialNerror

Comment: Hello, while I appreciate your sentiment, please take the time to accept the answer if it satisfies you, or ask any additional question that you feel is left unanswered